# Perl, Image::Magick, lost bytes when writing

Tags: perl, imagemagick

Good evening.

There is a problem.

```
my $image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Read($upload->tempname . '[0]');
$image->Write(filename => $upload_file_name, compression => 'None');
```

After executing the file sizes ($upload->tempname and $upload_file_name) do not match.
Image format is jpg ($upload->tempname is JPEG, $upload_file_name is JPEG).
In what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Image::Magick probably re-encodes the image, not using the exact same algorithm and parameters that it was originally encoded with.

If you're just renaming the file, why would you use Image::Magick anyway?

Comment: I want to not change the JPEG image. All other types of images I want to compress. With Image::Magitsk I determine mime type of image.

Comment: Then there's no reason to `Write()` the JPEG images after you've read them. You can copy them with `copy($upload->tempname.'[0]', $upload_file_name)` from File::Copy.